# Drupal Views Breaks slideshow when Cached

Tags: jquery, caching, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

When I go into the view advance settings and I try to set caching to my views, it ends up breaking my slideshow. It stacks all the images on top of each other. What am I doing wrong? Why does this do it? Also, what is even an optimal time to be set between query caching and render caching?

I'm a little hazy as to what exactly query and render caching is doing to my views. See my pictures and settings below:

Query and Render Cache settings:

[image: Query and Render Cache settings]

Broken Slideshow:
[image: Broken Slideshow]

Comment: Typically query and render caching should be the same. Do you get any JS errors in the console, though?

Comment: I didn't see any JS errors, and if they should be the same, should they be at the smallest time cached?

Comment: Optimally, it should be set for the longest time possible while refreshing often enough for new content to display (I usually default my views to 6 hours). As far as the slideshow output, try opening two tabs (cached vs un-cached) and compare the HTML and JS output.